# How to remove "year olds" from each row of a Dataset?

Tags: r

As in the image below, how would I remove each of the 'year olds' from the second column?

[Image of Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gdRk.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df$age5txt <- gsub(" year olds", "", df$age5txt)
```

where `df` is your dataset

Answer (score 0):

Using `trimws`

```
df$age5txt <- trimws(df$age5txt, whitespace = "\\s+year olds")
```